# How to convert a ms word file to pdf using java

Tags: java

How to convert doc to pdf using java ?

i am looking for an application to automatically convert a word file to pdf, with no user interaction at all, is this possible ?

what is the best way to achieve this, and an examples ?

And i cant use apache

i should add it only needs to do the text, nothing more

thanks :)

Comment: Use the Apache POI and Apache PDFBox combination, for an example.

Comment: Sorry i should have added, i am not able to use apache or spring for this application

Comment: My suggestion would be taking data from Msword as input and pass it to `iText` as String. This very easy cause Apache POI involves lot of complexity.

Comment: Edit your question to include the fact that Apache is not an option. Can you use any third-party software?

Comment: Yes third party software is ok and will do

Comment: and you don't want to use apache products because of... class warfare?

Comment: just a requirement, i can however use iText

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this without a third-party library, unless you write the entire PDF rendering engine yourself. And you *really* don't want to try doing that.

Apache PDFBox is generally the way to solve problems like this.

Comment: ok thanks, do you happen to have any examples of how this works ?